# /bin/sh: my_custom command not found inside Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, binary, sh

The context is the following: I need to run [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in a AWS Lambda service that is deployed and build using Docker. Since the docker image we use is not debian and does not includes ffmpeg, I created a binary file with the command and added it to the project files. Then, inside the Dockerfile, I create a link to these binary so the command is included in /bin.

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-nodejs6.10


# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

#add ffmpeg files
COPY binaries .binaries

#make link to ffmpeg
RUN  ln -s /app/.binaries/bin/ffmpeg /bin/ffmpeg

RUN npm install --global yarn
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn global add serverless@~1.24.1

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "yarn", "run", "deploy" ]
```

Although this seems to be working in local environment (the command responds when called from console inside docker's image), it does not work when deployed to stage:

```
/bin/sh: ffmpeg: command not found
```

Comment: Have you verified ffmpeg is a valid binary on the target platform, is configured with the execute permission, and what libraries does it depend on?

Comment: i haven't @BMitch. But I assumed that if the command is valid in my local docker container the same should be on deploy. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Do you mount any volumes when running locally? Is there architecture where you deploy on the same architecture you run locally?

Comment: nothing extra, it's all in that Dockerfile. Then we deploy to Lambda. Why do you ask about the architecture? To be able to test it in a different environment?

Comment: You cannot run an x86 binary on an arm64 platform, for example.

Comment: sorry @BMitch but I cannot find this info. Does aws lambda run on arm64 platform?

Comment: I do not know what platform lambda runs on, nor do I know the platform you are using for local development. The above was an example.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend replacing `CMD [ "yarn", "run", "deploy" ]`

with

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/.binaries/yarn"]
CMD ["run", "deploy"]
```

I think you have 2 problems:

1. Do you know that `yarn` is executable?  I don't know it is not, but explicitly calling `sh` means that it does not matter.
2. I don't think `yarn` is in the path.  Explicitly using the absolute path of `yarn` means it should not matter.

Comment: the app runs fine with yarn, @emory. The problem is it does not acknowledge ffmpeg command.

Comment: @ntonnelier I think I misdiagnosed your problem.  Can you run a modified script with the commands `echo ${PATH} && ls -lh /app/.binaries/bin/ffmpeg /bin/ffmpeg && which yarn ffmpeg` for diagnostic information.

Comment: here they are, @emory. But this is on my local environment that works fine. The problem is when we deploy AWS.
echo ${PATH}: /var/lang/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ls -lh /app/.binaries/bin/ffmpeg: ../bundles/e51bceda4ace9f7eab4c0f5d52f95d5c6787505a1ef741f3854ad2653d815cbb/usr
/bin/ffmpeg: ffmpeg version 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
which yarn ffmpeg: /var/lang/bin/yarn
/var/lang/bin/ffmpeg